# Only one part of the image is rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

When I render my project, the image is not rendered completely.

I chose 3840x2160, but my render is around half of it, only a single tile (which is 2048x2048 default) What's the problem?

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have a render region.  Look through the camera and use ctrl + alt + b

Comment: It didn't help.

Comment: @Denis try increasing the tile size to 3840x2160 (the dimensions of your render) and check if it works.